# How to load stylx file generated in ArcGIS Pro 3.1.1 in ArcGIS Pro 2.9.5

Tags: arcgis-pro, style

I have stylx files that were generated using ArcGIS Pro v 3.1.1. I am running ArcGIS Pro version 2.9.5. Cannot load the stylx file due to this. What are my options to load this 3x generated stylx file into ArcGIS Pro 2.x?

Comment: Did you try to add it or did you Import it? https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/help/projects/connect-to-a-style.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_6994EE9B9B85470BAAD371A046DE3B42

Answer (score 1):

ArcGIS Pro 3.x is a [breaking release](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-pro/announcements/get-ready-for-arcgis-pro-3-0/#:%7E:text=necessary%20API%20changes.-,Impacts%20of%20Breaking%20Changes,-Within%20a%20major) and 3.x files cannot be opened in ArcGIS Pro 2.x.

ArcGIS files are generally forwards compatible between major releases (i.e files created by 2.x can be read by 3.x) but not backwards compatible.  This is pretty common for other software.  The change from Word 2003 .doc to Word 2007 .docx caused much grief for those still stuck on Word 2003. As did the release of Python 3 which meant Python 2 scripts needed rewriting.

Though if you have Portal, you might be able to [load the stylx to Portal](https://community.esri.com/t5/arcgis-pro-questions/backward-compatibility-issue-for-arcgis-pro-style/m-p/1297110/highlight/true#M70006) and then download it to the 2.x Pro device.